# Selenium-IDE: How to select a stored link that is a "Name+RandomValue"?

Tags: selenium-ide

When I SAVE this as a link in Selenium IDE:

```
Command type  > Target id=title  > Value javascript{"Code" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111)}
```

It will become

```
"link=Code(numbers)" --->>Name of link will be "Code with random numbers".
```

My Question is, how do I store this name with random number and when I want to select this name and the random number "Link", how do I go about this?

I mean, I want to save this "link" with the Target as "Code" with a random number into a variable and select exactly the same one again?

Is it possible that I can select this link that I just created?

PLEASE HELP ME

Danny

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple question and very simple answer as well. This should work for you:

```
storeEval      | Math.floor(Math.random()*11111) | RandomNumber
type           | id=title                        | ${RandomNumber}
...
waitForVisible | link=Code${RandomNumber}
click          | link=Code${RandomNumber}
```

first line will store random value into the RandomNumber variable. each time you use varibale by ${xxx} the value will pop in the result action.